# Can GeoServer GetFeatureInfo return class name instead of raster pixel value?

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I have a land use / cover raster map published in GeoServer 2.6. When I use the query tool I get the pixel value (eg.: 1). Is there a way for geoserver to return what the value 1 means in my land use raster? For instance, 1:Agriculture; 2:Forest etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible with text/html info format through freemarker templates. This question has been considered in this recent thread in geoserver-users mailing list http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/47368

Comment: Thanks for finding this mailing list tread, I's exactly what I was after. I'll see if we can implement this using templates since, from what I understood in the discussion, it's not something implemented in GeoServer